# Groupby and subtract columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pandas-groupby

I have a time-series data with 4 columns and I would like to groupby the column `FisherID`, `DateFishing` and `Total_Catch`, and sum the column `Weight`. Also, I want to minus the value in column `Total_catch` with that in column Weight and its result will be kept in the new column named `DIFF`. And, I want to show the value in column `DIFF` that is higher than `0.1`.

Here is my  code.

```
df["DIFF"]=df.groupby(["FisherID", "DateFishing", "Total_Catch"]) ["Weight"].sum()-["Total_Catch"]>=0.1
```

My data:

```
FisherID    DateFishing Total_Catch Weight
1            24-Oct-11      0.9      0.2
1            24-Oct-11      0.9      0.264
1            24-Oct-11      0.9      0.37
2            25-Oct-11      0.7      0.144
2            27-Oct-11      8.2      0.084
2            27-Oct-11      8.2      0.45
3            27-Oct-11      8.2      0.61
3            27-Oct-11      8.2      7
3            29-Oct-11      0.64    0.184
```

Comment: It's not quite clear what the issue is. What is you actual and what is the expected outcome?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think you're looking for a *`groupby`* + *`transform`*:

```
df['Sum'] = df.groupby(
    ["FisherID", "DateFishing", "Total_Catch"]
)["Weight"].transform('sum')
```

Then, find `Diff` by subtracting the `Weight` col from `Total_Catch`.

```
df['Diff'] = (df['Total_Catch'] - df['Weight'])

df

   FisherID DateFishing  Total_Catch  Weight    Sum   Diff
0         1   24-Oct-11         0.90   0.200  0.834  0.700
1         1   24-Oct-11         0.90   0.264  0.834  0.636
2         1   24-Oct-11         0.90   0.370  0.834  0.530
3         2   25-Oct-11         0.70   0.144  0.144  0.556
4         2   27-Oct-11         8.20   0.084  0.534  8.116
5         2   27-Oct-11         8.20   0.450  0.534  7.750
6         3   27-Oct-11         8.20   0.610  7.610  7.590
7         3   27-Oct-11         8.20   7.000  7.610  1.200
8         3   29-Oct-11         0.64   0.184  0.184  0.456
```

Alternatively, if you're trying to subtract the grouped  `Weight` from `Total_Catch`, use:

```
df['Diff'] = df["Total_Catch"] -df.groupby(["FisherID", \
                   "DateFishing", "Total_Catch"])["Weight"].transform('sum')

df

   FisherID DateFishing  Total_Catch  Weight   Diff
0         1   24-Oct-11         0.90   0.200  0.066
1         1   24-Oct-11         0.90   0.264  0.066
2         1   24-Oct-11         0.90   0.370  0.066
3         2   25-Oct-11         0.70   0.144  0.556
4         2   27-Oct-11         8.20   0.084  7.666
5         2   27-Oct-11         8.20   0.450  7.666
6         3   27-Oct-11         8.20   0.610  0.590
7         3   27-Oct-11         8.20   7.000  0.590
8         3   29-Oct-11         0.64   0.184  0.456
```

---

### Querying rows

This section builds upon the result of the second option. Note that all of these options apply a boolean mask to a dataframe. If all you want is the mask, don't apply it to the dataframe. Simply apply the condition and print:

```
df.Diff > 0.1

0    False
1    False
2    False
3     True
4     True
5     True
6     True
7     True
8     True
Name: Diff, dtype: bool
```

If you want to extract all valid rows, there are a few options.

## *`df.query`*

```
df.query('Diff > 0.1')

   FisherID DateFishing  Total_Catch  Weight   Diff
3         2   25-Oct-11         0.70   0.144  0.556
4         2   27-Oct-11         8.20   0.084  7.666
5         2   27-Oct-11         8.20   0.450  7.666
6         3   27-Oct-11         8.20   0.610  0.590
7         3   27-Oct-11         8.20   7.000  0.590
8         3   29-Oct-11         0.64   0.184  0.456
```

## *`boolean indexing`*

```
df[df.Diff > 0.1]

   FisherID DateFishing  Total_Catch  Weight   Diff
3         2   25-Oct-11         0.70   0.144  0.556
4         2   27-Oct-11         8.20   0.084  7.666
5         2   27-Oct-11         8.20   0.450  7.666
6         3   27-Oct-11         8.20   0.610  0.590
7         3   27-Oct-11         8.20   7.000  0.590
8         3   29-Oct-11         0.64   0.184  0.456
```

## *`df.eval`*

```
df[df.eval('Diff > 0.1')]

   FisherID DateFishing  Total_Catch  Weight   Diff
3         2   25-Oct-11         0.70   0.144  0.556
4         2   27-Oct-11         8.20   0.084  7.666
5         2   27-Oct-11         8.20   0.450  7.666
6         3   27-Oct-11         8.20   0.610  0.590
7         3   27-Oct-11         8.20   7.000  0.590
8         3   29-Oct-11         0.64   0.184  0.456
```

## *`df.where`* and *`dropna`*

```
df.where(df.Diff > 0.1).dropna(how='all')

   FisherID DateFishing  Total_Catch  Weight   Diff
3       2.0   25-Oct-11         0.70   0.144  0.556
4       2.0   27-Oct-11         8.20   0.084  7.666
5       2.0   27-Oct-11         8.20   0.450  7.666
6       3.0   27-Oct-11         8.20   0.610  0.590
7       3.0   27-Oct-11         8.20   7.000  0.590
8       3.0   29-Oct-11         0.64   0.184  0.456
```

## *`np.where`* and *`df.iloc`*:

```
df.iloc[np.where(df.Diff > 0.1)[0]]

   FisherID DateFishing  Total_Catch  Weight   Diff
3         2   25-Oct-11         0.70   0.144  0.556
4         2   27-Oct-11         8.20   0.084  7.666
5         2   27-Oct-11         8.20   0.450  7.666
6         3   27-Oct-11         8.20   0.610  0.590
7         3   27-Oct-11         8.20   7.000  0.590
8         3   29-Oct-11         0.64   0.184  0.456
```

---

Note that these results have the index of the original `df`. If you want to reset the index, use *`reset_index`*:

```
df[df.Diff > 0.1].reset_index(drop=True)

   FisherID DateFishing  Total_Catch  Weight   Diff
0         2   25-Oct-11         0.70   0.144  0.556
1         2   27-Oct-11         8.20   0.084  7.666
2         2   27-Oct-11         8.20   0.450  7.666
3         3   27-Oct-11         8.20   0.610  0.590
4         3   27-Oct-11         8.20   7.000  0.590
5         3   29-Oct-11         0.64   0.184  0.456
```

Comment: Thank a lot COLDSPEED for your help. I would like to ask one more. Is it possible to groupby the FishID and sum the weight. For example:

FisherID DateFishing   Total_Catch  Weight   Diff        
 1            24-Oct-11         0.90           0.834   0.066

Comment: @Vanna `df.groupby("FisherID").Weight.transform('sum')`